# why would I call a function with the function name wrapped in parens?

Tags: c++, function, syntax, parentheses, function-call

I recently came across code that looked like this:

```
void function(int a, int b, int c){
  //...
}

int main(){
  //...
  (function)(1,2,3);
  //...
}
```

What is the point of wrapping the function name separately in parens?
Does it have any affect that would be different than `function(1,2,3);`?

Why does the language allow such syntax?

Comment: Did it make any difference to whatever output/return?

Comment: @FirstStep, I wasn’t in a position to run the actual code.  What I have above is contrived, but I'm looking for any example where (func)(arg) would be different than func(arg).  Something with scope? namespaces? lookup resolution?  the function itself was NOT a macro.  Maybe it was just a typo.

Answer (score 5):

The only case I can think of where it would matter is when `function` is defined as a macro.

In C, standard library functions may also be implemented as function-like macros (for efficiency). Enclosing the function name in parentheses calls the actual function (since the function name is not followed by a `(`).

As for why the language allows the syntax, a function call consists of an expression of pointer-to-function type followed by the arguments in parentheses. In most cases, the prefix is a function name (which is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function), but it can be an arbitrary expression. *Any* expression may be enclosed in parentheses, *usually* without changing its meaning (other than affecting precedence). (But see Jonathan Leffler's comments for some counterexamples.)

Comment: In "Effective Modern C++", Scott Meyers says: _“In `int x = 0;`
`x` is the name of a variable, so `decltype(x)` is `int`. But wrapping the name `x` in parentheses—“`(x)`”—yields an expression more complicated than a name. Being a name, `x` is an lvalue, and C++ defines the expression `(x)` to be an lvalue, too. `decltype((x))` is therefore `int&`. Putting parentheses around a name can change the type that decltype reports for it!
… C++14’s support for decltype(auto) […] means that a seemingly trivial change in the way you write a return statement can affect the deduced type for a function”_

Comment: The book goes on to give two examples:
`decltype(auto) f1()
{
  int x = 0;
  …
  return x;        // decltype(x) is int, so f1 returns int
}`
and
`decltype(auto) f2()
{
  int x = 0;
  …
  return (x);      // decltype((x)) is int&, so f2 returns int&
}`   That's mostly just an FYI — but I found it very interesting, and unexpected.  And it modifies slightly what you said in some unusual circumstances.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Weasel words added.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to suppressing function-like macro expansions, wrapping an unqualified function name in parentheses [suppresses argument-dependent lookup](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#basic.lookup.argdep-1). For example:

```
namespace meow {
    struct kitty {};
    void purr(kitty) {}
}

int main() {
    meow::kitty stl;
    purr(stl); // OK, ADL finds meow::purr
    (purr)(stl); // error; no ADL is performed
}
```